# Get all used excel range using win32com

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pivot-table, win32com

I'm creating a pivot table using win32com and it's working fine but the problem now is that not all the excel data is been loaded. My excel has over 8 millions on lines of data and excel can only open about 1 million lines. Using the code below, only about a million lines are being read for the pivot table. Is there a better way to implement this to be able to read all the data

I first thought of setting self.excel.Visible = False and not open the workbook, but that didn't work

```
input_path = "path.xlsx"
output_path = "report.xlsx"
pt_worksheet_name = "Diagnostic"
data_worksheet_name = "Sheet1"
pivot_table_name = "myPivotTable"
pivot_table_rows = [
                        ['metric','Metric'],
                        ['value','Values']
                    ]
pivot_table_columns = [
                        ['value','Values']
                    ]
pivot_table_filters = [
                        ['market','Market'],
                        ['wallet','Wallet'],
                        ['period','Period']
                    ]
pivot_table_values = [
                        ['ntran', "Transactions", -4157],
                        ['spend', "Spend", -4157]
                    ]
hide_row_detail = None

pt_global_diagnostic_properties = Properties(input_path=input_path,
                            output_path=output_path,
                            pt_worksheet_name=pt_worksheet_name,
                            data_worksheet_name=data_worksheet_name,
                            pivot_table_name=pivot_table_name,
                            pivot_table_rows=pivot_table_rows,
                            pivot_table_columns=None,
                            pivot_table_filters=pivot_table_filters,
                            pivot_table_values=pivot_table_values,
                            hide_row_detail=hide_row_detail)


import win32com.client as win32
import os

#Class to create pivot tables 
class CreatePivotTable(object):
    """
    A class that creates pivot tables given the correct parameters
    """
    def __init__(self, properties) -> None:
        
        # create Excel application object
        self.excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        self.excel.Visible = True
        self.properties = properties

        if self.properties.input_path == self.properties.output_path:
            
            self.work_book = self.excel.Workbooks.Open(self.properties.input_path)
            self.data_sheet = self.work_book.Sheets(self.properties.data_worksheet_name)

            self.work_book.Sheets.Add().Name = self.properties.pt_worksheet_name
            self.pivot_table_sheet = self.work_book.Sheets(self.properties.pt_worksheet_name)
            self.pt_location = len(self.properties.pivot_table_filters) + 8

        else:

            self.data_work_book = self.excel.Workbooks.Open(self.properties.input_path)
            self.data_sheet = self.data_work_book.Sheets(self.properties.data_worksheet_name)

            print(self.data_sheet.UsedRange.Address)

            if os.path.exists(self.properties.output_path):
                self.work_book = self.excel.Workbooks.Open(self.properties.output_path)
            else:
                self.work_book = self.excel.Workbooks.Add()

            self.work_book.Sheets.Add().Name = self.properties.pt_worksheet_name
            self.pivot_table_sheet = self.work_book.Sheets(self.properties.pt_worksheet_name)
            self.pt_location = len(self.properties.pivot_table_filters) + 8

            # If the workbook is new, delete the default "Sheet1" worksheet
            if 'Sheet1' in [sheet.Name for sheet in self.work_book.Worksheets]:
                self.work_book.Sheets('Sheet1').Delete()
    
        # grab the pivot table source data
        PivotCache = self.work_book.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=1, #win32.constants.xlDatabase
                                                        SourceData=self.data_sheet.UsedRange)
        # create the pivot table object
        self.PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=f'{self.properties.pt_worksheet_name}!R{self.pt_location}C1',
                                                        TableName=self.properties.pivot_table_name)

        # selecte the pivot table work sheet and location to create the pivot table
        self.pivot_table_sheet.Activate()
        self.pivot_table_sheet.Cells(self.pt_location, 1).Select()

        try:
            # close data worksheet
            self.data_work_book.Close(SaveChanges=False)
        except:
            pass

    def run(self):
        self.addPivotTable()
        self.addTextBoxs()

    def RGB_TO_INT(self, rgb):
        """
        Convertes RGB values to a single integer
        """
        RGB_Int = rgb[0] + (rgb[1] * 256) + (rgb[2] * 256 * 256)
        return RGB_Int

    def addPivotTable(self):
        """
        Add data to pivot table
        """

        if self.properties.pivot_table_filters is not None:
            for i, value in enumerate(self.properties.pivot_table_filters[::-1]):
                field = self.PivotTable.PivotFields(value[0])
                field.Orientation = 3 #win32.constants.xlPageField
                field.Position = i + 1
                # field.Caption = value[1]

        if self.properties.pivot_table_rows is not None:
            for i, value in enumerate(self.properties.pivot_table_rows):
                field = self.PivotTable.PivotFields(value[0])
                field.Orientation = 1 #win32.constants.xlRowField
                field.Position = i + 1
                # field.Caption = value[1]

        if self.properties.pivot_table_columns is not None:
            for i, value in enumerate(self.properties.pivot_table_columns):
                field = self.PivotTable.PivotFields(value[0])
                field.Orientation = 2 #win32.constants.xlColumnField
                field.Position = i + 1
                # field.Caption = value[1]

        if self.properties.pivot_table_values is not None:
            for i, field in enumerate( self.properties.pivot_table_values):
                print(i)
                data_field = self.PivotTable.AddDataField(
                        self.PivotTable.PivotFields(field[0]), field[1], field[2])
                data_field.Orientation = 4 #win32.constants.xlDataField
                data_field.Position = i + 1

        if self.properties.hide_row_detail is not None:
            for value in self.properties.hide_row_detail:
                self.PivotTable.PivotFields(value).ShowDetail  = False

        #Add pivot table designs and options
        self.PivotTable.RowAxisLayout(1)
        self.PivotTable.ColumnGrand = False
        self.PivotTable.RowGrand = True
        self.PivotTable.SubtotalLocation(1)
        self.PivotTable.TableStyle2 = 'PivotStyleDark2'
        self.PivotTable.PageFieldWrapCount = 3
        self.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
        self.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleColumnStripes = True

        #Widen the cell width
        for column in self.pivot_table_sheet.UsedRange.Columns:
            column.AutoFit()
            column.ColumnWidth += 8
        # self.PivotTable.RefreshTable()

    def save(self):
        """
        Save the workbook
        """
        if os.path.exists(self.properties.output_path):
            self.work_book.Save()
        else:
            self.work_book.SaveAs(self.properties.output_path.replace("/", "\\"))


piovt_table = CreatePivotTable(pt_global_diagnostic_properties)
piovt_table.run()
```